# How to enable access control for MongoDB with Docker (Plesk)

Tags: mongodb, docker, plesk, access-control

How do I enable access control for my MongoDB server? 
This line shows up in the log:

> CONTROL [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for
>   the database. I CONTROL [initandlisten] ** Read and write access to
>   data and configuration is unrestricted.

I use Plesk to start MongoDB and I have read their manual about it
but it doesn't tell me how to enable access control since I can only add environment variables and volume mapping via the Plesk control panel such as /data/db and /data/configdb.

I'm able to use a terminal to login without credentials to create a superadmin and all the roles, but that doesn't solve the unrestricted access.

I can also access files within the container with this:

```
docker exec -it mongo /bin/bash
```

And I see this directory: docker-entrypoint-initdb.d 
but I don't know what to put there. Also packages that I installed inside the container like vim don't persist and are lost after a restart.

Furthermore I have no idea where Plesk is storing the docker-compose.yml file. Is this a file that only belongs inside a image file?

If I change the /etc/mongod.conf and add this:

```
security: authorization: enabled
```

nothing happens after restart, could I get some help with this?

**system information:**

- Plesk Onyx 17.8.11 Update 25
- Host: CentOS 7.5.1804
- Container: Ubuntu 16.04
- Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

Answer (score 0):

You should read the library/mongo image documentation : https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

If you want to use your own mongo configuration file, put it somewhere like /etc/mongo/mongod.conf in your container (with volume or COPY).
After that you have to tell to mongo to use it as configuration file :

```
$ docker run --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
```

Or in docker-compose :

```
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        command: --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
```

I can't help you for the location of Plesk docker-compose.yml, try to use `find` command.

I hope it will help you.